# Android Studio V2 with no JAVA folder

Tags: java, android, android-studio, keytool

I am trying to run the keytool, but I can't find the Java on my machine. I know I haven't install java on this computer, but Android Studios is running very happily and I'm able to compile and run the emulator. I am using Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre (Embedded JDK) in the project Structure.

Do I need to install a stand alone version of Java to get Keytool to run?
Does Android Studio have its own keytool.exe somewhere?
Why is this happening??

Thanks

Comment: As far as I know 1) The `jre` folder **is** this "JAVA folder" you mean 2) You might need the JDK for the keytool

Comment: As far as your setup, you *should* download and setup the standalone JDK for any Java development.

Comment: So Androis STudios own java would not conflict with another JDK installation?

Comment: no it won't conflict with your installed JDK

Comment: There are separate executables, why would they conflict? Kinda like asking does having Firefox and Chrome installed conflict

Comment: What OS are you running?

Answer (score 2):

found key tool in \Android\Android Studio\jre\bin

Comment: Strange that this folder is named `jre` when it is really a full JDK.

Answer (score 0):

```
Project Structure > SDK Location
```

JDK Location:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.*
```

Comment: he might have it but he doesn't know X'D

Comment: I looked in the \Program Files\ I don't have a Java folder

Comment: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html

Comment: download the proper JDK for your OS then use the answer to set the JDK